# NoLinkedYouTubeAccount trying to connect googleplus page manager

Tags: youtube-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

OAuth dialog flow
1. Select Account
I select my email

1. Select Account (again)
   I am given a choice of my email again and I googleplus page i manage.
   I choose the manager account.

Then i Get NoLinkedYouTubeAccount when trying to get the account profile.
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?alt=json&access_token={access_token}

The manager account does have a youtube profile.

How can i get around this?  I want to be able to get the profile information from the selected account.

The account selected is not a service account, it is an account that shows up when i am a manager of a page.

Comment: Please describe clearly what you want to achieve, and which steps you are taking. I have a feeling you are trying to use Service account

Comment: It is not a service account, I have tried that and that makes sense because the service account truly doesn't have a youtube account.

Comment: I am working on the same question. Testing out the api via apigee, with oauth 2.0, the user is offered two ways to login. One of them gives a bad token that doesn't work with the api (some times for good reasons). It seems to me that the youtube api is offering the end user an option that shouldn't be offered (because it doesn't work). I put the issue here https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4860 .